# Heroes of Might and Magic: can't get out of town

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-4

I am playing a scenario in Heroes of Might & Magic IV ("A Tale of Two Enemies") at the Novice level in which I start in a town in one corner of the map and there is an opponent I have to defeat at the other corner. However, I cannot get out of my town. Both exits are guarded by Waspworts which are much higher level creatures than me and my army, so they crush me no problem if I challenge them.

I have done everything the town area has to offer (captured saw mills, picked up gems, etc).

How can I level up to defeat the Waspworts and progress further?

Comment: Do you have the scenario name at hand? Then I could give it a try myself and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @Scorch91 How do I find out what the scenario name is?

Comment: Can't remember this particular scenario, but if your starting area offers enough ressources to build up to stronger creatures you will eventually be strong enough to break through the waspworts. They are tier 3 creatures, so once oyu get access to tier 3 yourself you should be able to beat them in a week or two. A screenshot of your current situation would be helpful.

Comment: @Dulkan Well, my hero is level 2 and all my squires and crossbowmen are level 1 and everything is in the corner area is done, so I have no more way to level up. The waspworts have no problem nuking the level 1 squires that I have.

Comment: Getting stronger in HoMM doesn't mean you level up your hero. Ressources will accumulate and you get access to more powerful creatures eventually. More powerful and higher number of troops usually has a stronger effect than your hero. Only high level heroes are strong enough to tip on their own.

Answer (score 5):

I finally figured it out. There is a third way out of the area in addition to the two guarded by waspworts:

[image]

Even though the wall looks solid, the circled area actually has a gate in it and you can ride right through.

Comment: Well, that's a garrison. You can recognize it by the flag, which displays the ownership and the towerlike structure.